# Web application DbContext first usage for EF performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I'm developing a web api application that uses EF6.

I instantiate a DbContext for each Http request I receive.

From what I know, instantiating the **first** DbContext in the system (The first Http request I get) takes alot of time.

I was wondering if by creating a DbContext in the Startup method of the application on another thread and immediately disposing it will result in better performance -
it won't make the first request that actually sets up the database to be so slow?

How do another people handle the first creation of the database?

Comment: Is this "from what I know" based on the experience from this real app you mention or maybe the question is theoretical, you read about it somewhere and you haven't really measured how much time does it actually take in your case?

Comment: It is more of a theoretical question, I'm still not in a state where I can test it in my team's project. I actually haven't seen a lot of people mention it, and wondered why others don't just create a useless DbContext at startup, to have EF configure itself and have the first query run faster on context creation and SaveChanges? Are there any cons to doing this?

Comment: A small lag for few users from time to time isn't probably something they would bring back to you to fix it if you don't build a real time system.

Comment: Regardless of the purpose of the application. In general, why not do this?

Comment: I don't believe the context views are built (which is what makes the 1st request take longer) just by newing up and disposing a DbContext. You would need to actually invoke a query or a command against that DbContext during app start in order for this to work.